# Elastic search - exporting index from a cluster to a different cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

Can I use the *snapshot and restore* module of elastic search to export one index to all together to a new  elastic search cluster.

For e.g

Can I export all the indices from development cluster to QA cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump, we made it for exactly this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the snapshot & restore feature to backup indices from one cluster and move them to another cluster. Once you have created the snapshot on your development cluster, you can copy it over to your QA cluster and restore it.

The advantage over just performing a direct copy of the index folder is that you do not need to shutdown the clusters. The snapshot is a point in time capture of the indices state and can be run without taking the cluster offline.