# How to copy my local index data to another ip's elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have 3 indexes in my http://localhost:9200 those are `index1`, `index2` and `index3`.

I need to copy all these indexes to http://some_ip:9200. How can I copy all my index data into another IP's elasticsearch.

Comment: i think you can replicate 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/replica-shards.html

Comment: Is this a one time action or do you want to continuously do this?

Comment: just one time action

Answer (score 1):

You can use logstash ([see how to install](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html)) with an `elasticsearch` [input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html) and [output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) plugins. Your `logstash.conf` file should look like this:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
   index => "index1"
  }
}
filter {
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
   host => "some_ip"
   port => 9200
   protocol => "http"
   index => "index1"
   manage_template => false
   workers => 5
 }
}
```

You can then run this with `$ bin/logstash -f logstash.conf`

Rinse and repeat for `index2` and `index3`

Comment: can we do using elasticsearch dsl?

Comment: What logstash does under the hood is [scanning](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) your source ES host to extract documents from your indices (index1, index2, and index3) and then sending those retrieved documents using the [`_bulk`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html). The logstash solution I'm suggesting prevents you from re-inventing the wheel to move your data.

Comment: actually i need to perform this action in live cluster. i don't want to install logstash there. i want to write simple python script so that these changes are done.

Comment: Then you are probably interested in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25971140/elastic-search-exporting-index-from-a-cluster-to-a-different-cluster which suggest to use the [snapshot & restore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) feature.

Comment: by using logstash i have tried it is copying but it is saving as single file which is named as logstash. i need to save files individually named as index1,index2 etc

Comment: I've edited my answer and added an `index` property in the output plugin. Please try again.

Comment: now it is not created any index on some_ip elasticsearch

Comment: If the indices don't exist on your target host at some_ip, try to create them first.